# WebSphere configuration with ant & jython

Tags: ant, websphere, jython

I have been able to successfully configure resource environment entries with the Jython script below.  I call the Jython script with the ws_admin program in my local app servers bin directory.

I work on a team where ant is the preferred technology in our build process.

I've looked around the web for documentation on configuring WebSphere with ant and so far it looks like to me that one is mainly able to call programs like ws_admin from ant.

Is it possible to configure resource environment entries using ant directly instead of using a Jython or Jacl script?  If not, how can I go about setting up an ant task to reduce the amount of Jython that is needed to set up resource environment entries?

Here's my current Jython script that sets up resource environment entries.  Ultimately looking for ways to reduce our dependence on Jython...

```
# Set up Variables used within this script
objServerAttrs  = AdminControl.completeObjectName('WebSphere:type=Server,*')
node            = AdminControl.getAttribute(objServerAttrs, 'nodeName')
server          = AdminControl.getAttribute(objServerAttrs, 'name')
provider        = "Test_ConfigurationProvider"
providerFactory = "com.DG_ConfigurationFactory"
providerClass   = "com.DG_Configuration"

# Function for creating resource custom properties
def createResourceCustomProperty(envEntry, propName, propValue):
    propSet = AdminConfig.showAttribute(envEntry, 'propertySet') 
    if propSet == None:
        propSet = AdminConfig.create('J2EEResourcePropertySet',envEntry,[])

    name = ['name', propName]
    value = ['value', propValue]
    propAttrs = [name, value]
    AdminConfig.create('J2EEResourceProperty', propSet, propAttrs)
    return

# Create the resource environment provider
AdminResources.createResourceEnvProvider(node, server, provider)
AdminResources.createResourceEnvProviderRef(node,server,provider, providerFactory, providerClass)

# Create the resource environment entries
## Context Configuration
envEntry = AdminResources.createResourceEnvEntries(node,server,provider, "Context Configuration", "test-config/context")
createResourceCustomProperty(envEntry, "deployment.environment", "IDE")
createResourceCustomProperty(envEntry, "server.context", "com.context.DG_WebSphereServerContext")
createResourceCustomProperty(envEntry, "user.context", "com.context.DG_WebSphereUserContext")
createResourceCustomProperty(envEntry, "log.directory", "C:/Development/WebSphere/Logs")
createResourceCustomProperty  (envEntry, "file.directory", "C:/Development/WebSphere/AppFiles")

## Mail Configuration
envEntry = AdminResources.createResourceEnvEntries(node,server,provider, "Mail  Configuration", "test-config/mail")
createResourceCustomProperty(envEntry, "enabled", "false")
createResourceCustomProperty(envEntry, "mailSessionJndiName", "mail/MailSession")

## User Repository Configuration
envEntry = AdminResources.createResourceEnvEntries(node, server, provider, "User Repository Configuration", "test-config/userRepository")
createResourceCustomProperty(envEntry, "ldap.provider.url", "ldap://test.com:389/cn=users,dc=com")
createResourceCustomProperty    (envEntry, "ldap.security.principal", "cn=was_user,cn=users,dc=com")

# Save changes to the configuration
AdminConfig.save()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with WAS 7, in addition to admin console and wsadmin, a third way to configure the server was introduced, namely [properties file based configuration](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/txml_property_configuration.html). This new administrative model supposedly "eliminates the need to write complex wsadmin scripts" as explained at [related Education Assistant presentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/v1r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.was_v7/was/7.0/Administration/WASv7_PropertiesFileConfig/player.html).

What you do, basically, is configure a single environment, export the parts of configuration that are of interest to a portable properties file, and later use this file as an input to a single line of `wsadmin` script, which applies the configuration in the properties file to another target server. So you get rid of many lines of Jython and work with a much simpler artefact, which is a property file with a simple and familiar syntax.

In addition to above links there is a [nice article about this feature](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0904_chang/0904_chang.html) at Developerworks.